# Decrementing an alphabetical value in php

Tags: php

Base on the answer [Decrementing alphabetical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762579/decrementing-alphabetical-values)

what about if i have a character like this $char='AF', how can i make it to $char='AE' and so on ?

**UPDATE**

Here is my complete solution:

```
function decrementChar($par){
    if(strlen($par)>=2){
        $str= substr($par,0,-1); 
        $strdec= substr($par,-1);           
        $strdec=$strdec=='A'?'':chr(ord($strdec) - 1 );
        return $str.$strdec;
    }
    return chr(ord($par) - 1 );

}
```

Comment: try here http://codepad.org/m70oYumi

Comment: This question was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.  You might consider adding more detail and code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your string is a hex value, you can use the following code:

```
$char = 'AF';
$value = hexdec($char);
$value--;
$char = dechex($value);
```

if you string is just a string:

```
$len = strlen($char);
$char[$len - 1] = chr(ord($char[$len - 1]) - 1);
```