# PHP - Loop through letter backwards

Tags: php, loops, char

I have noticed some strange behaviour in PHP while trying to loop through letters:

```
for($i='a'; $i<='c'; $i++)
  echo $i;
```

gives the expected `abc`, but if I want to reverse it

```
for($i='c'; $i>='a'; $i--)
  echo $i;
```

I end up in an infinite loop, returning and endless string of `c`

It seems like the `$i--` does not have any effect on chars.
Is there a way i can do this loop anyway without using ASCII tables, to keep it as understandable as possible to read?

Comment: What is this? Are you looping characters? LOL

Comment: Yes I have a specific purpose, which requires me to loop characters.

Comment: Is `strrev` an option for you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Comment: I would build an array of letters then use array_reverse and a foreach loop, that is much easier!

Comment: Please satisfy our curiosity and share the purpose you have for this. I'm certain there will be a better way

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762579/decrementing-alphabetical-values for what seems to be the answer.

Comment: Purpose: I create a table, where the rows' lables contain the letters. I dont want to use the `chr` function, because numbers are not as legible as characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:

`<?php
foreach (range('c', 'a') as $char) {
    echo $char;
}`

Pass your start and end value to the range() function.