# Decrement character with php

Tags: php

Why is it that it's ok to increment character but not decrement with PHP?

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $a = "a";
    echo $a. "<br>";  //a
    echo ++$a. "<br>";  //b
    echo --$a. "<br>";  //b
>
```

Is there a simple way as `--$a`to decrement a charrater?

There was a solution by using `chr`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: And why are you trying to increment a *letter*?

Comment: how much simplicity you need???

Comment: Increment `chr(ord($a)+1)` and Decrement `chr(ord($a)-1)`

Comment: Funny example. It is a good question )

Comment: @PedroLobito - I hate to tell you that you're wrong, but you're wrong.... PHP supports Perl-style character incrementing; and there are perfectly valid use cases for it as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrementing alphabetical values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762579/decrementing-alphabetical-values)

Comment: @MarkBaker, always learning..I'll remove my comment, thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no direct way to decrement alphabets. But with a simple function you can achieve it:

```
function decrementLetter($Alphabet) {
    return chr(ord($Alphabet) - 1);
}
```

[Source, thanks to Ryan O'Hara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762579/decrementing-alphabetical-values)

Comment: Thank you. i will use this!

Answer (score 6):

There is no simple way, especially if you start with multi-character strings like `'AA'`.

As far as I can ascertain, the PHP Internals team couldn't decide what to do when

```
$x = 'A';
$x--;
```

so they simply decided not to bother implementing the character decrementor logic

Comment: i don`t understand.. why increment works but decrement no?

Comment: @jekaby Mark just made it clear. I don't think you will get a better answer.

Comment: @jekaby - you don't understand? What should the value of `$x` be after the code I've shown above? Should it be null? Should it be an empty string? Should the code throw an exception?

Comment: 'A' will be. But why? Why only increment is working for letters?

Comment: Why should it be `'A'` still, instead of `''` or `null`? leaving the value as `A` is counter-intuitive

Comment: @MarkBaker, please can you tell me why i got downvote?

Comment: @FrayneKonok Maybe because you only partially answered the question (not my downvote).

Comment: @FrayneKonok - I don't know why you got downvoted.... perhaps because your answer doesn't support starting from a string like `AA`? Perhaps because of how it will handle decrementing an `A`?

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this. Output is `a b a`.

```
$a = "a";
echo $a. "<br>";  
echo $next = chr(ord($a) + 1). "<br>";
echo $prev = chr(ord($next) - 1 ). "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

As [chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85) mentioned: "***Character variables can be incremented but not decremented***"

---

> PHP supports C-style pre- and post-increment and decrement operators.

Incrementing/Decrementing Operators

1. `++$a`  Pre-increment   Increments `$a` by one, then returns `$a`.
2. `$a++`  Post-increment  Returns `$a`, then increments `$a` by one.
3. `--$a`  Pre-decrement   Decrements `$a` by one, then returns $a.
4. `$a--`  Post-decrement  Returns `$a`, then decrements `$a` by one.

> **Note:** The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and
>   strings. Arrays, objects and resources are not affected. Decrementing
>   `NULL` values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1.

---

**SRC:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 0):

Simple function you can achieve it:

```
function decrementChar($Alphabet) {
return chr(ord($Alphabet) - 1);
}
```

Comment: Already have this answer, with link to the answer it came from.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this.

```
function stringDecrementer($string)
{
    $len = strlen($string);
    if ($len == 1) {
        if (strcasecmp($string,"A") == 0) {
            return "A";
        }
        return chr(ord($string) - 1);
    } else {
        $s = substr($string, -1);
        if (strcasecmp($s, "A") == 0) {
            $s = substr($string, -2, 1);
            if (strcasecmp($s, "A") == 0) {
                $s = "Z";
            } else {
                $s = chr(ord($s) - 1);
            }
            $output = substr($string, 0, $len - 2) . $s;
            if (strlen($output) != $len && $string != "AA") {
                $output .= "Z";
            }
            return $output;
        } else {
            $output = substr($string, 0, $len - 1) . chr(ord($s) - 1);
            return $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work for 2 length values with "A" at the second position, like, "HA", "IA" etc.

Comment: it is now fixed, thanks for the correction.