# Why can't you use -- to change the value of character, but when you do ++ it does exactly that

Tags: php

Explanation

```
<?php
    $a="b";
    $a++;
    echo $a;
?>
```

The output here is 'c',

```
 <?php 
    $a="b";
    $a--;
    echo $a;
 ?>
```

whereas the output here remains 'b'. Can someone explain why is it that things work this way, and if I wanted the output in the second case to be 'a' how could I do it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37027367/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 funny thing is that, it works fine with integers; go figure.

Comment: Yeah I also tried that it's just really weird.

Comment: so you're (probably) left with using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37027657/1415724 from the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/37027277/1415724 that Rizier123 gave.

Comment: There was even a proposal for this: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/alpanumeric_decrement?s[]=decrement and a PR: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/546/files

Comment: Thanks for the help, figured it thanks you you Fred -ii-, Rizier123

Comment: You're welcome @Zmija15

Comment: @Rizier123 do you feel the question's a duplicate of [Decrement character with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37027277/1415724) ?

Comment: Yes. It shows a way how to get the decrement working with a function and also says why it probably wasn't implemented in PHP.