# PHP 2 chars decrement (AB -> AA)

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am implementing some export functions using PHPExcel.
Since PHP can increment alphabet automatically it had been working fine but I have an issue when trying to decrement it. 
I can decrement a single character like this `$decremented = chr(ord($someChar) - 1);`, but it does not work on 2 characters (such as 'AA','BB', .. etc.)

Is there any way that I can decrement two characters? Like 'ZZ' -> 'ZX', 'AA'->'Z'

Any help or thoughts would be really appreciated!

Comment: Yes there is but its not going to be a simple statement, you are going to have to do some testing to make sure you dont decrement below an `A` and a lot more besides.

Comment: But surely you must have done something similiar when incrementing so that when you increment `Z` you get `AA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a decrement function that will work for you:

```
function decrement($str) {
  $index = strlen($str)-1;
  $ord = ord($str[$index]);
  if ($ord > 65) {
    // The final character is still greater than A, decrement
    return substr($str, 0, $index) . chr($ord-1);
  }
  if ($index > 0) {
    // Strip the final 2 characters and append a Z 
    return substr($str, 0, $index-1) . 'Z';
  }
  // Can't be decremented
  return false;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/WaaKY

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762579/decrementing-alphabetical-values/29488999#29488999 is better actually.  Mine doesn't properly handle `BBX` through `YYX` values.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody wrote a function for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488999/2105482).

```
function decrementLetter($char) {
     $len = strlen($char);
     // last character is A or a
     if(ord($char[$len - 1]) === 65 || ord($char[$len - 1]) === 97){ 
          if($len === 1){ // one character left
               return null;
           }
           else{ // 'ABA'--;  => 'AAZ'; recursive call
               $char = decrementLetter(substr($char, 0, -1)).'Z';
            }
     }
     else{
         $char[$len - 1] = chr(ord($char[$len - 1]) - 1);
     }
     return $char;
}
```