# Why doesn't PHP Increment work as expected

Tags: php

During exporting mysql data to excel I'm facing folling problem.
I have to varables $rowNumber & $col. I have ti decrease (-1) both.
The attached code works for $rowNumber, but not for $col. Any idea?

The result is always:

```
 182 AD
 183 AE
```

As you can see increase works with both.

```
<?php

$rowNumber = '183';
$col = 'AD';

$rowNumber--;
$col--;

echo $rowNumber,' ' , $col, "\n";

$rowNumber++;
$col++;

echo $rowNumber,' ' , $col, "\n";

?>
```

Comment: you can only increment string in PHP, not decrement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488999/1213708 is probably most relevant in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to treat those as number and extract number to column for that I have written a method `getNameFromNumber` you can see it is working with your expectations...

```
<?php

$rowNumber = 183;
$col = 29;//'AD';

function getNameFromNumber($num) {
    $letter = chr(65 + $num % 26);
    $num2 = intval($num / 26);
    return ($num2 > 0) ? getNameFromNumber($num2 - 1) . $letter : $letter;
}


$rowNumber--;
$col--;

echo $rowNumber,' ' , getNameFromNumber($col), "\n";

$rowNumber++;
$col++;

echo $rowNumber,' ' , getNameFromNumber($col), "\n";

?>
```

**output**

```
182 AC
183 AD
```

Comment: What if the column is `AQ` for example?

Comment: Updated my code use `getNameFromNumber` for it

Comment: I see 'AQ' will not work, but in my case 'AC' will be the highest collumn ever.
So the solution fits for my needs.

Comment: It may be for now, but what happens when someone else comes along and tries to modify your code?

Comment: @NigelRen updated code will work for all cases I test upto 10000 cols

Comment: that's perfect - thx a lot!